# Docker Document Server "Download Failed"

Tags: node.js, docker, onlyoffice

I'm trying to test OnlyOffice locally. I'd like to open .docx files on my website.
I was quite confused, but I think I dont need Community Server for this, right?
The Document Server looks fine. Even when I set the volumes.. For now, lets use this:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d -p 80:80 --restart=always onlyoffice/documentserver
```

The Document Server runs fine. When I open `http://localhost` I see "The Document Server is running..."

Then I tried to follow the Node.js example instructions
https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/example/nodejs

The server is running fine. I did changed the config/default.json to have

```
{
   "server": {
   ...
      "siteUrl": "http://localhost"
   }
}
```

The Node.js example also runs fine

But when I create a file... these errors appears:
[image]

Comment: what is the output of `docker container logs <container-name>`

Comment: There is no error in logs.. just this:

` * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                               [ OK ] 
 * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                               [ OK ] 
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
Starting supervisor: supervisord.
Generating AllFonts.js, please wait...Done
onlyoffice-documentserver:docservice: stopped
onlyoffice-documentserver:docservice: started
onlyoffice-documentserver:converter: stopped
onlyoffice-documentserver:converter: started`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that Document Server doesn't have access to the storage and the Document editing service cannot upload the file for editing.
The link to the file specified in the [document.url](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/config/document#url) should be accessible from the document editing service. (from inside the container)

Both errors are describe [here](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/troubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that was from inside the container.